# html/rails form. Input

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

This is a simple question but I can't seem to find a solid answer. I simply want to know if this is valid? it's a basic form_for with in input at the bottom.

## Form

```
 <%= form_for @snitch, html: { class: "form-actions", method: 'delete' } do |form| %>
 <span class="button-text"><%= link_to 'NO WAY!', home_base_url_or_default(root_path), rel: "modal:close" %></span>
 <button type="submit" class="button button--modal delete-snitch" data-snitch-id="<% @snitch.token %>" value="Yes, delete it.">
 <% end %>
```

Is the third line valid? specifically where it says `data-snitch-id="<% @snitch.token %>"`? if it is not. can someone help me figure out how I can do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML [data attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) are perfectly valid and widely supported. They're used to store custom data in an element. You can create elements with those attributes in rails helpers as well.

```
<%= button_tag "Yes, delete it.", type: :submit,
    data: {"snitch-id" => @snitch.token}, 
    class: 'button button--modal delete-snitch' %>
```

The only problem with your example is that you're not printing the value of `@snitch.token`. You should be using `<%= @snitch.token %>` instead of `<% @snitch.token %>`

Answer (score 0):

Use #{　} expression instead.

```
data-snitch-id="#{@snitch.token}"
```